# How to flatten dataframe variable from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, hierarchy, flatten

I have two data frames. One is used as a group definition (palette) with their respective pieces (colors). Some of them would be formed by combinations. On the other hand, I have a test data frame with different combinations of groups (non-strictly-palette), like color + palette. I would like to have a final data frame, with all non-strictly-palette with their respective pieces (colors).

```
# Definition dataframe ----

n = 3

Blues   = paste0('blue',  seq_len(n))
Greens  = paste0('green', seq_len(n))
Rainbow = c('red', 'Greens')

d_create = data.frame(
  group = c(
    rep(c('Blues', 'Greens'), each = n),
    rep('Rainbow', 2)
  ),
  piece = c(Blues, Greens, Rainbow)
)

d_create

#     group  piece
# 1   Blues  blue1
# 2   Blues  blue2
# 3   Blues  blue3
# 4  Greens green1
# 5  Greens green2
# 6  Greens green3
# 7 Rainbow    red
# 8 Rainbow Greens

# Test dataframe ----

Rainbow_plus = c('orange', 'Blues', 'Rainbow')

d_test = data.frame(
  group = c(
    rep('Blues',        length(Blues)),
    rep('Rainbow_plus', length(Rainbow_plus))
  ),
  piece = c(Blues, Rainbow_plus)
)

d_test

#          group   piece
# 1        Blues   blue1
# 2        Blues   blue2
# 3        Blues   blue3
# 4 Rainbow_plus  orange
# 5 Rainbow_plus   Blues
# 6 Rainbow_plus Rainbow

# Desired dataframe ----

d_desired = data.frame(
  group = c(
    rep('Blues', n),
    rep('Rainbow_plus', (2*n+2))
  ),
  piece = c(
    Blues,
    c('orange', Blues, 'red', Greens)
  )
)

d_desired

#           group  piece
# 1         Blues  blue1
# 2         Blues  blue2
# 3         Blues  blue3
# 4  Rainbow_plus orange
# 5  Rainbow_plus  blue1
# 6  Rainbow_plus  blue2
# 7  Rainbow_plus  blue3
# 8  Rainbow_plus    red
# 9  Rainbow_plus green1
# 10 Rainbow_plus green2
# 11 Rainbow_plus green3
```

**EDITED:**

I've changed dataframe examples. Now, d_create consist on:

1. "Blues" one_depth_group
2. "Greens" one_depth_group
3. "Rainbow": (mix_group) simple+one_depth_group

While on d_test, we have:

1. "Blues": one_depth_group
2. "Rainbow_plus": simple+one_depth_group+mix_group

Note that `red` and `orange` are new colors not previous defined, so they remain unchanged.

I think I have to loop over `d_test$piece`, and check if each piece is present on `d_create$group`. If it is present, expand to their corresponding peaces. If not, remain unchanged.

```
lapply(d_test$piece, function(x) {
    check1 = x %in% d_create$group
    if (!check1) {
      x
    } else {
      lapply(d_test[d_test$group == x,]$piece, function(z){
        check2 = z %in% d_create$group
        if (!check2) {
          z
        } else {
          lapply(d_test[d_test$group == z, ]$piece, function(m){
            check3 = m %in% d_create$group
            if (!check3) {
              m
            } else {
              'infinite_loop'
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }

  })
```

But I don't want to write each possible loop, because in real world, it would be unpredictable for future flatten job. Maybe using `while`. Some help? thanks

Comment: apologies, I tried to understand what you want to do, but to be frank, I fail to understand the operation. What I think you want to do is expanding the "group"-colours (e.g. Greens, Reds) in  `d_test`. Thus, if there is a `Greens`, the `d_desired` shall expand to (in this case) 3 rows with `green1`, `green2`, and `green3`. If this is correct, a less nested operation would be to look for the "group" colours (Reds, Yellows, Greens, etc) and expand (create new rows) for the "sub"-colours, e.g. in case of Reds --> reds1, reds2, ... redsn. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I expected some misunderstood. I found some difficulties to explain the problem. The case you say, would be correct, if all expanded needed groups would be all the same nesting depth

Comment: For example, the "mix" group on d_test is build by a simple color 'blue1" and a group "Reds" of one nested depth. So final "mix" would be "blue1", "red1", "red2" and "red3". The problem comes when have some simple or one-depth-nested group and a new problem-build-group "NewGroup" formed by two-depth-nested "Brown/Light/(light_brown1,2,3...)" and "Brown/Dark/(dark_brown1,2,3...)". Then "NewGroup" should be expanded twice, "Reds" only once, and "blue1" untouched

Comment: I've modified the dataframes and some explanation

Comment: Have you tried `while loop` .  If not, try that.  Alternatively you may use `graph theory` here by using `igraph` or some other package, to find out the nodes.

Comment: I thought it would be possible with while loop, but i can not get it working. Some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may code a while loop, in this case-

- First change the column name of `df_test` (transaction table) with suffix `1` into the corresponding column name of `d_create` (master table) so that loop may be started and end point may also be defined.
- In every iteration of the while loop, `left_join` your transaction table with master table so that you get an extra column in your transaction table along with respective level of hierarchy (first level in first hierarchy).
- After that `coalesce` your first column of transaction table (resulted) with the newly created column.
- The loop will end only when there are no further values to match from master table, i.e. new column if created will contain only same values and no extra value.

I hope I have made the logic pretty clear.

```
library(dplyr)

#rename one column of d_test
d_test <- d_test %>% rename(piece1 = piece)

#actual while loop
j = 1
while(any(d_test[,(paste0('piece',j))] %in% d_create$group)){
  d_test %>% left_join(d_create, by = c('piece1' = 'group')) %>%
    rename(!!paste0('piece', j +1) := piece) %>%
    mutate(piece1 = coalesce(get(paste0('piece', j+1)), piece1)) -> d_test
  j = j +1
}

#desired output
d_test %>% select(group, piece1)

          group piece1
1         Blues  blue1
2         Blues  blue2
3         Blues  blue3
4  Rainbow_plus orange
5  Rainbow_plus  blue1
6  Rainbow_plus  blue2
7  Rainbow_plus  blue3
8  Rainbow_plus    red
9  Rainbow_plus green1
10 Rainbow_plus green2
11 Rainbow_plus green3
```